# Stripe Checkout with multiple products not built in Stripe Dashboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, backend

Good evening everyone. I have one big question which contains others. I hope it's not a problem, it's all connected.

- I have implemented stripe to my site and I wouldn't want to create every single stripe product in the stripe dashboard but manage my products and bring them all together to the stripe checkout when the user confirms his purchase. Someone know if it's possible?
- If it is I currently have prices created dynamically in js files in the client directory and I know all prices should be kept in the backend so I need to change the whole approach?

[image: folder directory]
[image: array of products]
[image: checkout.js render]

And finally if it is possible to have my products redirected to the Stripe checkout page how do I insert in the server.js session the unit_amount in line_items corresponding to the cart total?

[image: server.js]
[image: stripe section checkout.js]

Comment: Your first question is a little vague and elaborating on it would be beneficial to the community members trying to provide assistance. In your provided snippets, you are using `line_items.price_data` which is the correct way to provide Price details to Checkout Sessions in an adhoc fashion. Does that not meet your needs, is there something you're seeing when using that approach that you want to change? Or are you possibly trying to ask something else? Looks like your later questions are built on the first one so getting a better understanding on what you're asking there will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Toby. Yes, he does not meet my needs. Basically I would like the user to see the total price of the products he has chosen to purchase at the stripe checkout. To make it simple I would like the unit_amount of price_data to contain the total of the products in the cart

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not clear what default behavior you're seeing that you're not happy with. Providing specific and explicit examples would be incredibly helpful to help the community understand your concern. Using `price_data` does cause the Checkout Session to show the specified amount when you direct your Customer to the Checkout Session. Are you seeing something different? What are you seeing on the Checkout Session? What do you want to see instead?

Comment: I honestly don't think I could have been clearer than that. In any case, I solved the problem.